# Proper use of the vinculum to indicate repeating decimal.

Tags: notation, arithmetic

A nerdy debate with a colleague leads me to ask this question:

To be used correctly, does the vinculum **HAVE** to only be placed over the *shortest* sequence of digits that repeat after a decimal?

For example, to indicate 1/3, is it ok to write $0.\overline{33}$ instead of $0.\overline{3}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be placed behind the decimal point? $\frac{100}{7} = \overline{14.2857}$?

Comment: I thought that was just a symptom of mathematicians' and math fans' preference for shorter notation regardless of its impact on clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok to write $$\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline{3}=0.\overline{33}$$

See also e.g. the *[related example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vinculum.html)* $0.\overline{111}$ in Wolfram's MathWorld. This representation could also be used to enhance readability.